# How to select date of last 5 days?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to select last 5 days prio a given date?

given date: `2015-11-14`

select query should return like below output -

```
2015-11-14
2015-11-13
2015-11-12
2015-11-11
2015-11-10
```

Comment: Last 5 days of what? Seriously....you need to provide some level of information if you expect any help.

Comment: Last 5 days of what? You need to be more specific. Are you referring to getting the 5 days prior to a given date?

Comment: @SeanLange jinx.

Comment: Yes, referring to getting the 5 days prior to a given date.

Comment: Is your starting point the current date or from some record in the DB? Do you need to generate values if none exist, or do you want 5 most recent days for which you have records? If you're referencing something in a table, give us a small sample of the columns, so we can use consistent naming in the answers.

Comment: I think you should read about `APPLY` oprator: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with dates as (
      select cast(getdate() as date) as dte
      union all
      select dateadd(day, -1, dte)
      from dates
      where datediff(day, dte, getdate()) <= 4
     )
select  *
from dates
order by dte desc;
```

Obviously, you can reference any other date you want instead of `getdate()`.  Your example suggests that the current date is 2015-11-14, which was a while ago.

Answer (score 0):

you can use tally table as below

```
 Declare @dt date = getdate()       
 Select top (5) Dt = DateAdd(day, -Row_number() over (order by (select null)), @dt) from master..spt_values
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @startdate date = getdate();
DECLARE @NbDays int = 5;

WITH ListDate AS (
SELECT 1 as LP, @startdate as Dt
UNION ALL
SELECT LP + 1, DATEADD(DAY,-1,Dt)
FROM ListDate 
WHERE LP < @NbDays 
)

SELECT * FROM ListDate;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @fromData date = getdate()
DECLARE @daysBack int = 5

;WITH dates AS (

    SELECT 1 as LP, @fromData as Dates
    UNION ALL
    SELECT LP + 1, DATEADD(DAY,-1,@fromData)
    FROM dates
    WHERE LP < @daysBack
)

SELECT * 
FROM dates
```